# Changing value of hidden form with ID of text input forms with onfocus

Tags: html

How do you change the value of a hidden form with the id's of text forms? I have something like the following:

```
<form name="form" action="file.php" method="post">
<input type="hidden" name="dessert" id="dessert" value="">
Favorite cake: <input type="text" name="cake" id="cake" onfocus="dessert.value=this.id"><br>
Favorite pie: <input type="text" name="pie" id="pie" onfocus="dessert.value=this.id"><br>
Favorite taffy: <input type="text" name="taffy" id="taffy" onfocus="dessert.value=this.id"><br>
<input type="submit value="Go."><br>
```

I'm pretty unfamiliar with html, so I'm having trouble changing the value of the hidden form with the id of the text input onfocus.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
<form name="form" action="file.php" method="post">
<input type="hidden" name="dessert" id="dessert" value="">
Favorite cake: <input type="text" name="cake" id="cake" onfocus="document.getElementById('dessert').value=this.id"><br>
Favorite pie: <input type="text" name="pie" id="pie" onfocus="document.getElementById('dessert').value=this.id"><br>
Favorite taffy: <input type="text" name="taffy" id="taffy" onfocus="document.getElementById('dessert').value=this.id"><br>
<input type="submit value="Go."><br>​​​​​​​
```

Using the format:

```
onfocus="document.getElementById('dessert').value=this.id"
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/zLz9u/)**

Answer (score 1):

Your code works, you just have a syntax error.

```
<input="hidden" name="dessert" id="dessert" value="">
```

Should be:

```
<input type="hidden" name="dessert" id="dessert" value="">
```

notice the "type="

Works in Chrome: [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/NNrLT/)

Comment: Thanks, I made a mistake while typing the example. Fixed.